# Correspondence Search for Marker Recognition

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0, pose-estimation

my general goal is to do marker based pose estimation.
For this I need the correspondence between image coordinates and object coordinates.

So after detecting the circular Markers, I need to determine, that the top Left Marker is A, the first on the right side is B, then comes C and then D. Like in the example image below.

[image]

Now my first idea was to do this distance based. 
Since I know the width of my markers in real world, I can do a easy calculation of euclidian distance multiplied by the real world size of one pixel.

```
Example:
realMarkerWidth = 2,7
realWorldSizeOfOnePixel = MarkerWidth / RealMarkerWidth
distance = euclidiantDistance(P1,P2) * realWorldSizeOfOnePixel
```

---

**My current approach:**

With this information the correspondence search algorithm goes like this.

Notation:

Initial measured distances are stored in the set P =(dist(m1,m2),...,dist(mi,mi+1)}

Detected markers will be in the set D = {d1,d2...,dn}

1. Initally measure the distance between all labled Markers.  P =
   {dist(A,B),dist(A,C),dist(A,D),dist(B,C),..., dist(D,C)
   Note: This is done only once and before runtime of the pose estimation     program.
2. If |D| >= 3 then

   dref= d1;

   dj = d2;

   while ( j < |D|)

   measure dist(dRef,dj) and comapare it, to all entries in P.
      Assume, that the current dist is the one, which has the highest  similarity to one entrie in P. Increase the occurence of assumed markers by one

3.dref = Marker with higesht occurence value

4.Do this for all detections in D

---

**Example:**

dref = A and the other detected markers are B and C. 
Then the programm will count 2 times A one time B and one time C.
Occurence of A is higher than all others, therefore dref must be A,

---

**Problem:**

This approach works only in 2D Space, As long as the markers are all in the same plane, the distances are corrected. But if some of the markers are not in the same plane, the distances are wrong and therefore the distances can't be compared anymore. See the image below for an example.

[image]

---

**Question**

I know that there are things like aruco markers, but my question aims, to do recognition with only white circular markers.

Does anyone know an approach, how I could improve my system?
Like I said in the beginning, my goal is to do pose estimation with white circular markers. I am open to any solution which brings me nearer to this goal.